# Trying to insert a <div>

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a button layout for my Chromecast. This will eventually be a webpage to cast so I can scrap online video.

But my problem is that I cannot insert this center `<div>`.  The code goes from left to right after the `class="topbarBackground"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head style="margin:0;">
        <style>
            .topbarBackground {
                background-color:#222222;
                width:1440px;
                height:70px;
                position: fixed;
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:1;
            }

            .scrollbuttonLframe {
                opacity:0.5;
                width:70px;
                height:70px;
                position: absolute;
                left:25px;
                top:0px;
                z-index: 4;
            }

            .scrollbuttonRframe {
                opacity:0.5;
                width:70px;
                height:70px;
                position:absolute;
                right:25px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:4;
            }

            .tabBackground {
                opacity:0.5;
                width:1250px;
                height:70px;
                position:absolute;
                left:95px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:2;
            }

        </style>
        <div class="topbarBackground">
            <button class="scrollbuttonLframe">
            </button>

            <div class="tabBackground">
            </div>

            <button class="scrollbuttonRframe">
            </button>

        </div>

    </head>

    <body style="margin:0;">

    <p> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br>
    </body>

</html>
```

the i `<br>` section is for a scroll bar test

Comment: Edit your title and the rest to something with proper English and punctuation so we can figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: so sorry im brand new to we development just a little project of mine and im learning with w3c schools which i hear is bad. besides the point. i just realized i made the center button a division so it was perfect i was expecting a grey area like the 2 side buttons so dumb question. like i said im new it was an oversight.

Comment: After trying to fix your HTML indentation, and question formatting, I notice that you used some `div` tag in the `head` tag, which is invalid, you should put the `div` in the `body`. Please try to write proper english, being a beginner does not excuse your poor english.

Comment: Ignore all the nonsense you read about w3schools. That was old news from years ago. It's as good as some and better than most.

Answer (score 0):

I asked 2 questions today and I got ragged on my lack of care for capitalization both times. This question was a bit quick and if I spent extra time working through my work I would have realized I did what I wanted to do and expected the wrong thing, resulting in confusion. I decided to put this code in the  because I plan on working through some node.js which will be the body of my webpage. I felt that it would be a bit more ordered to put this navigation bar in the head fully separating my code sections. I'm new to code in general though so maby when I start the next processes I might find that the code does need to belong in the body.